# R find row value based on value in another column without ifelse

Tags: r, apply

I have a `data.frame` built up as follows:

```
a   b   c   d   column_name
1   2   3   4   a
2   3   4   1   b
3   4   1   2   c
4   1   2   3   d
```

Now I want to get the value for each row, of the column that matches the name in column_name. I build this with an `ifelse` like so:

```
df$value <- ifelse(df$column_name=="a", df$a, 
ifelse(df$column_name=="b", df$b, 
ifelse(df$column_name=="c", df$c, 
ifelse(df$column_name=="d", df$d, "NA"))))
```

However this is not very pretty and efficient. With more then 4 possible columns it becomes impossible to use.

Does anyone know a more efficient and beautiful way? I tried `apply()`, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a column index by `match`ing the 'column_name' with the column names of the dataset (`match(df$column_name, colnames(df))`), `cbind` it with the row index (`1:nrow(df)`), extract the elements of 'df' based on this and assign (`<-`) it to create the 'value' column.

```
df$value <- df[-ncol(df)][cbind(1:nrow(df), match(df$column_name, colnames(df)))]
df$value
#[1] 1 3 1 3
```